# javascript variables problem

Tags: javascript

```
$.getJSON("/data/data/com.android.tcptest/files/BPL.json", function(data) {
        var i = 0, dataSize = data.length, tmpArray = [];
        for(i; i < dataSize; i++){
            tmpArray.push ([data[i].Time.substring(0, data[i].Time.length -2).replace(/:/g, ""),data[i].Bid ]);
        }
        return tmpArray;
    });
    $.plot($("#chart"), [ tmpArray ]);
```

How can I use `tmpArray` outside `getJSON()` function. My programme doesn't work.
Thanks!

Comment: define it somewhere else outside `getJSON`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize tmpArray outside of the `getJSON` block.

Edit: Quentin is right, the array would be empty. You'll also need to make the request synchronous. I wrote the following example, hope it helps: http://jsfiddle.net/mXHfC/

Comment: Could you should me how to do that?

Comment: Then you'll just be passing an empty array to `plot`.

Comment: Could u tell me how to do that? I tried "tmpArray =[]" outside getJSON but still fail.

Answer (score 0):

Asynchronous JavaScript and XML is asynchronous.

You can't return from it, any more then you could return from:

```
$('button').click(function () {
    return tmpArray;
});
$.plot($("#chart"), [ tmpArray ]);  /* Does this method really expect an array consisting of a single value that is another array? */
```

The code in the callback won't execute until after the HTTP response has arrived (or the button has been clicked).

**Do the work inside the callback**.

```
$.getJSON("/data/data/com.android.tcptest/files/BPL.json", function(data) {
    var i = 0, dataSize = data.length, tmpArray = [];
    for(i; i < dataSize; i++){
        tmpArray.push ([data[i].Time.substring(0, data[i].Time.length -2).replace(/:/g, ""),data[i].Bid ]);
    }
    $.plot($("#chart"), [ tmpArray ]);  
});
```

Comment: I tried this before, this work in brower but android. Put plot outside function works on android but only with some stastic values. like [[1,2],[2,3],[4,5]]

Answer (score 0):

getJSON is asynchronous, you can not use the array before the function is returned!

```
$.getJSON("/data/data/com.android.tcptest/files/BPL.json", function(data) {
        var i = 0, dataSize = data.length, tmpArray = [];
        for(i; i < dataSize; i++){
            tmpArray.push ([data[i].Time.substring(0, data[i].Time.length -2).replace(/:/g, ""),data[i].Bid ]);
        }
        $.plot($("#chart"), [ tmpArray ]);  
        //return tmpArray;
    });
```

Comment: This is working fine with brower but when I put this into android--->failed. I tried to put plot outside getjson and give it some specific value(like[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]). It works. Confuse!!!

Comment: Are you sure the android device is calling the success function? Is it creating an array correctly?